# Segue with Keyboard, iOS

Tags: ios, keyboard, uistoryboardsegue

I have a segue (normal push) from Screen A to Screen B where Screen B has a keyboard. I want to make it such that the keyboard on Screen B also segues in (from left to right). Currently, it just appears without the segue/motion because first responder is called on Screen B on ViewWillAppear. Any suggestions of how to do that?